# Horizontal image scrolling with scalability

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal scrolling image panel that consists of large images with a max height of 800px. When the browser is resized I want the entire selection of images to get smaller/bigger according to the size of the browser window. I want the top of the images to hang 200px at the top with a 30px margin at the left (when page is loaded) and 30px at the bottom.

I am really new to this so any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated
What is the most efficient way to do this?
Many thanks in adavnce

The HTML looks like this so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Dean Pauley — Recent work</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="infoleft">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Dean Pauley</a></li>
                <li>Graphic Design</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="inforight">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
            <img src="images/NFN800.jpg" width="948" height="800"  id="fullsize" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

#infoleft { 
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}

#infoleft ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#infoleft ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 30px;
}       

#inforight {    
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    right:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}

#inforight ul {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#images {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    bottom:30px;
    top:200px;
    width:25000px;
    height:800px;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

img {
    padding:10px;
}   

a {
    text-decoration:none; color:#000;
}

a:hover {
    color:#0080ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the image-related size measurements to % rather than px. That way the size of your images, paddings, margins, etc. will change with the size of the browser window although the proportions will stay the same.

example: img {width:80%; height:60%; etc.}